# Error 400 en petición POST angular

Tags: angular

ME tira un error 400 al hacer una petición por POST desde Angular a mi API tengo que mandar un dato email y su email correspondiente por lo que hago lo siguiente:

```
testRecoverY(email) {
   let json = JSON.stringify(email);
   let params = 'email='+json;
   let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
   return this.http.post(this.url+/api-email/', params,{headers})
}
```

He de añadir que me tira el siguiente error

> detail: "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" }

En POSTMAN si me hace la petición

Comment: puedes poner que espera el backend? osea que tipo de dato? Al parecer estas mandando un string en vez de un objeto a tu backend y como envias los datos desde postman?

Answer (score 1):

No sé exactamente qué tipo de JSON quieres crear, pero asumo que es algo como

```
{ "email": "miemail@email.com"}
```

Pero lo que estás mandando es algo como

```
email=miemail@email.com
```

Aquí estoy asumiendo que el parámetro `email` es simplemente un string.

Deberías comprobar qué tipo de JSON espera el servidor y generarlo correctamente.